# Deluge change download location from shell

Tags: bash, apache, shell

I am trying to create a script and can't change the download location from shell I tried making it delete core.conf then downloading mine after the core.conf is created but it's not working here is my code and if you have a question just ask:

```
watch -n 1 rm /var/lib/deluge/config/deluge/core.conf &&
wget --output-document="/var/lib/deluge/.config/deluge/core.conf" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamtis/deluge-installer/master/var/lib/deluge/config/deluge/core.conf
wait
rm -f /etc/init.d/coredl.sh
rm -- "$0"
```

Github repo https://github.com/iamtis/deluge-installer don't make fun it's just a fun project XD

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "it's not working" is not a helpful statement.  Please describe the exact error.

Comment: sorry I am trying to make it download the core.conf file to the server so that it will change the download location for the torrents but when I download the core.conf it doesn't change anything am I changing the wrong file? here is the repo if you were wondering the code https://github.com/iamtis/deluge-installer